# Stream HTTP via ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming

I want to stream a video stream over HTTP but ffmpeg fails with this message:

> [tcp @ 0x5636b74e4740] Connection to tcp://127.0.0.1:4000 failed:
>   Connection refused http://127.0.0.1:4000/: Connection refused

My command is:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.64:554 -vsync 0 -vcodec copy -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -f mp4 http://127.0.0.1:4000/
```

I just trying to convert RTSP video to be played on browsers using HTTP. Obviously I need a HTTP server for this but no idea how should I do this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `Obviously I need a HTTP server for this` Did you attempt to install, or obtain access to an http server yet?

Comment: @szatmary I'm not sure if that helps. I think the OP is confused about what should be done. Mustafa, do you want to have web clients to be able to open a website and watch the stream live on an HTML page?

Comment: @szatmary as slhck said, I'm confused about what should I do. Yes, I am able to convert RTSP video stream to MPEG-TS over UDP but you can't play it from browser. I want to convert RTSP somehow to something so that browser would be able to play  it.

Comment: `Obviously I need a HTTP server for this` Did you attempt to install, or obtain access to an http server yet? <- Do this

Comment: @szatmary well installing apache is easy but I don't know what to do next or how to configure it actually

Comment: Set up webdav so you can upload files, then have ffmpeg upload the media (Just like in your example) then give the url of the uploaded manifest to a player. There are many tutorial on the internet on how to configure Apache.

Answer (score 0):

to run ffmpeg you have to install ffmpeg on your system first...and make sure it's in the same folder as the html file. then run the command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.64:554/Streaming/Channels/101 -fflags flush_packets -max_delay 5 -flags -global_header -hls_time 5 -hls_list_size 2 -hls_flags delete_segments -vcodec copy -y video1.m3u8
```

it converts the stream to a video file with the m3u8 extension.

after the command is run make a display on the web using html :

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.17.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
      .cctvplay
      {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-top: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='cctvplay' >
      <video id="my-video" style="text-decoration: none" class="video-js" controls poster='' preload="auto" width="520" height="440" data-setup=" {}" >
        <source src="video1.m3u8" />
      
    </div>
         <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.17.0/video.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

good luck...